# Getting XML data from an https request in .net?

Tags: asp.net, xml, xml-deserialization

I need to create an ASP.net web page application displays a report based on XML data.

I'm told that I must get my XML data from https://www.example.com/foo.xml.  I would like for my ASP.net application to get the data server side, interpret it, and display a report.

I need to know to things:

1) How do I make the .net framework retrieve the XML data from https://www.example.com/foo.xml at run-time.

2) How do I get the data set to an appropriate object type so that my program can read it?

Answer (score 0):

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
byte[] data = wc.DownloadData("https://www.example.com/foo.xml");
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
MyClass mc = (MyClass) xs.Deserialize(ms);
```

This assumes that the server is sending XML in UTF8 format and `MyClass` is an implementaion of the XML model in .NET which can be deserialized from that XML.

Comment: I have tried this code exactly as you suggest.  However, I'm having the problem that the application thinks that I'm not authenticated.

Comment: @Rice: if the app thinks  you're not authenticated, then chances are that you're not. The code above doesn't set any credentials.

Comment: @Rice What authentication? You did not tell us anything about authentication in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) and [HttpWebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx) to execute the request and retrieve the raw response. The [GetResponseStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponsestream.aspx) method will get you a raw response stream, which you can wrap using [XmlReader.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/756wd7zs.aspx) in order to read the response as XML.

Those classes should get you moving in the right direction.